# Spring MVC AJAX / JSON -> json.min.js - where can I get a newer version?

Tags: ajax, json, spring-mvc

I am using this sample Spring MVC project with AJAX / JSON support:
https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-samples/mvc-ajax/

There is a json.min.js file and I want to know what file this is. So where can I get a newer version of it? Where is this originally hosted?

Link to json.min.js
https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-samples/mvc-ajax/trunk/src/main/webapp/resources/json.min.js

Does anyone know?

Comment: What specifically do you want to know about this file?  Why do you think it is out of date?  Why do you think the Spring SVN repo is not the best place to find this file?

Comment: First, I do not want the minified version in case of debugging. Also I want to know if this is a standard file or a special one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is: http://www.json.org/js.html

Comment: This does not reference than file sorry.

Answer (score 0):

It is a minified version of http://www.json.org/js.html plus a couple of (not minimized) functions

http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?97613-MVC-Ajax-example-project-gt-json-min-js&p=327246#post327246